# Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() GD installed but not recognized

Tags: debian, gd, php-7

I'm running my server under Debian 8 with PHP7.
I install GD with `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`, which installed a lot of additional stuff.

the phpinfo page doesn't have the usual gd library part I used to see with PHP5. Searching for the word "gd" only hits on a line from the PHP Credits section: "GD imaging: Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Jim Winstead, Jouni Ahto, Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre-Alain Joye, Marcus Boerger".

I checked in `/etc/php/mods-available` and there is a `gd.ini`.
`php -i | grep gd` says :

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

`php --ini` says :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

I tried another test in a testgd.php file :

```
<?php
if(!extension_loaded('gd')) echo "No GD extension" ;
if(!function_exists('gd_info')) echo "<br/>No GD info fonction" ;
?>
```

Which as expected displays both messages.

I'm lost. I don't know if I missed a basic thing like enabling a module/extension/donut or something, but I spent 2 hours trying to figure it out before asking here. I'm out of ideas.

Has someone an idea what I need to do ?
Thank you.

EDIT : restarting (not reloading) apache after everything, saved the day.

Comment: My phpinfo() on php 7 with working GD shows a gd section.

Did you installed php7.0-gd later on? Apache requires a restart before the php extension is loaded. So did you restart Apache?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question about the time I installed php7.0-gd. I installed it a few hours ago, but my LAMP install is 2 months old. For second question, I restarted apache several times, but I think I missed the important one, as after a restart I finally see a GD section, and the test scripts is now OK.   TL;DR : restarting apache saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours on a Ubuntu Xenial server, but in my case the cause was different:

- There were traces of `php5` in the system
- PHP from the command line would run `php-7.0` but Apache would use `php5`
- The `php5-gd` package was not available anymore

My solution was to purge any trace of `php5` and restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt remove --purge "php5.*"
sudo apt install --reinstall php7.0
sudo service apache2 start
```